# Statistics of DynamoDB with CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I get **ConsumedReadCapacityUnits** statistics graph of DynamoDB table, the **Sum** statistics was like this:

```
               +-------------+
               |             |
               |             |
               |             |
               |             |
---------------+             +-------------------
```

but the **Average** statistics was like this:

```
---------------+             +-------------------
               |             |
               |             |
               |             |
               +-------------+
```

How to explain this statistics?

Comment: Can you add images of the graphs?

Answer (score 0):

I have got an answer from aws.

In this case, I read data each time become less, so the average go down. But the read times increased substantially, so the sum rise